# Java: unexpected type error when creating a stack of floats

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a stack of floats, but I'm getting this error:

```
error: unexpected type
    Stack<float> stack;
          ^
  required: reference
  found:    float
```

**EDITS**

*Accepted Answer:* (from below)

Java can't use primitives to parameterize a generic variable. You'll have to use Float (capital "F"). – markspace

*Note about being a duplicate:*

I see why this is being marked as a duplicate but, because the other answer doesn't mention stacks specifically, this question is still useful as a way to guide people to the other answer (and inherent problem). That is, someone googling specifically about stacks won't find the other answer without this one pointing them there. With that in mind:

stack of bytes

stack of shorts

stack of ints

stack of longs

stack of chars

stack of doubles

stack of booleans

Comment: Java can't use primitives to parameterize a generic variable.  You'll have to use `Float` (capital "F").

Comment: Yep, what @markspace said

Comment: You may use [trove](https://bitbucket.org/trove4j/trove/src/master/) to put primitives into collections or use [autoboxed types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)